# When I put require('nodemailer'); at begging of code, all of the code doesn't work

Tags: node.js, referenceerror

(I already Installed nodemailer)

```
  "name": "APIName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

Hello I have an error before initialization, however I don't understand what's wrong (even I searched google). can anyone tell me what's wrong? Error also occurs to content variable . (Cannot access 'content' before initialization) Thanks you.

**register.js:114 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'nodemailer' before initialization
at send (register.js:114)
at HTMLButtonElement.register (register.js:128)**

````
const emailInfo = {
    host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: 2525,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        "user": "Don't try to see :P",
        "pass": "Do not try to see :P",
    }
};

const content = {
    from: "aewr@naver.com",
    to: "myemail@inbox.mailtrap.io",
    subject: "YESS",
    text: "HI"
}

async function send(data) {
    nodemailer.createTransport(emailInfo).sendMail(data, function (error, info) { // line 114 ERROR POINT
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(info);
            return info.response;
        }
    });
}


async function register() {
    if (!(checkNickName() && checkEmailCorrect() && checkPw() && comparePw())) return;
    console.log("WORK") // check if it works to here
    await send(content); // line 228 ERROR POINT
}```
````

Comment: Have you required/imported `nodemailer` module? Try to add this at the beginning of your code `const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");`. BTW, it says "HTMLButtonElement" in the error message, are you trying to use it on the front-end? Strongly don't recommend that(security tricks and all of that)...

Comment: Oh Yeah thanks you. I forgot it xD btw I already installed nodemailer.

Comment: When I put ```const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')``` to beginning of code, all of code doesn't works. 

` (Installed nodemailer)

Comment: "all of the code doesn't work", what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: All of code in register.js file

Comment: Exactly every code like password check etc